# what does character 's' stand for in the formula for workload distribution

Tags: c, function

I got a question which i tried to understand i googled it but cannot find relevant answer.

> For any distribution, if `a` is the total time required by the 1st TA, `b` is the total time required by the second TA and `c` is the total time required by the 3rd TA, minimize `z = abs(a-b)+abs(b-c)+abs(c-a)`.
>
> Input The first input is `N`, the number of test cases. Each test case has 1st input as `Q`, the number of questions. Then exactly `Q` numbers (space separated) in 1 line, each denoting the time required for every question. Output For every test case, one number in a line, `z`, the minimum value which is possible.

can someone tell what is `s` in the formula?

Comment: Huh? The formula doesn't have an s in it, except as part of abs...

Comment: This question only makes sense in perl.

Comment: Anyway, `abs` means "absolute value", not `a * b * s`.

Answer (score 1):

`abs()` is not `a*b*s`, as you might have thought. It's a [C library function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) to compute the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of an integer.

It is prototyped in `stdlib.h`.